# What all can I do with Clash of Clans gems?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I know of the obvious things such as purchasing another builder or a shield. I know I can boost production of gold and elixir. I know I can use gems in order to make up for a shortage of resources when purchasing upgrades. Is this all the possible things you can do with gems or is there something more?

Comment: You can also speed things up with gems.  Buildings, research, hero upgrades, and even troops/spells.  Also you can boost unit/spell production and hero healing speeds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a bunch of things that gems do for you. Most are related to the reduction of timers or bypassing resource requirements.

- Buying builders can *only* be done with gems, which you've already mentioned.  There is a max of 5 builders, with each builder costing more gems than the last
- Buying shields can be done with gems, although you can get them from being attacked as well
- You can boost unit production at barracks with gems
- You can boost spell creation at the spell factory with gems
- You can boost the production rate of collectors (gold, elixir, dark elixir) with gems
- You can heal your heroes with gems (bypassing the timer)
- You can make up for a resource shortage when beginning to build/upgrade/research/train something with gems
- You can also bypass wait times on build/upgrade/research/train processes with gems

As far as gem acquisition and strategy is concerned, I wrote [a pretty popular article](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/clash-of-clans-gems/) on the subject, which may be of interest.

Comment: that's you?! awesome! i read your article back in september :-)